# Avoid temporary 404 errors during deployment with tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat7, opengrok

Every time I copy `OpenGrok/dist/source.war` to `/var/tomcat/webapps/`, the tomcat generates blank error pages with `404 Not Found` errors to my users, during a couple of seconds immediately after such copying.

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 02 Apr 2013 19:00:14 GMT
Connection: close
```

This is not acceptable.  Am I not deploying correctly, by manually copying a `.war` file into a tomcat directory, or is it an OpenGrok bug of some sort?  How do I ensure there's not a single visitor that'd be getting an undue `404` during the deployment process?

Comment: If you need a 100% uptime you may want to look into a loadbalancer and at least 2 tomcat nodes. Then you can update one while the other handles the requests, and after the first is updated correctly you can switch to it and update the second one.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings, you have to be kidding me!  I'm obviously not looking for 100% uptime, but I didn't know that tomcat is a amateur-hour solution that requires a disgraced multi-second downtime with normal use.  I'd be very happy to ditch tomcat7, if this is indeed the only way around this; recommendations of decent alternatives are very welcome (I only use tomcat to run OpenGrok).

Comment: do you have unpackWars set to true? How large is your application, do you perform expensive startup actions?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings, I'm using the defaults; the `.war` files do get unpacked automatically, so, most likely unpackWars is indeed set to true.  OpenGrok is not that big -- my `.war` is about 4MB, and it's on a dedicated server.  I'm not aware of any specific expensive startup actions (but then I didn't actually write OpenGrok).  My OpenGrok instance does have a couple of medium-sized Lucene index files, totalling 1.1GB, but those aren't supposed to be loaded during the startup (else, it wouldn't be taking only a couple of seconds anyways).

Comment: Then try setting unpackWars to false in your tomcat config https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Standard_Implementation this should at least reduce your downtime. Furthermore I would suggest looking at the logs to determine the startup behavior of your app.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings, from your words, that doesn't sound like a solution; I want no downtime at all when some minor change is made to a .war; are other Java servlet servers likewise affected?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27432/discussion-between-leonard-brunings-and-cnst)

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat 7 has a feature called parallel deployments. Using this feature it is possible to have multiple instances of your app running under the same context path.

This blog post explains it nicely: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/06/zero-downtime-deployment-and-rollback.html

To sum it up you need to manually version your wars when you add them to your appBase.

```
cp foo##001.war apache-tomcat-7/webapps/
cp foo##002.war apache-tomcat-7/webapps/
```

You may want to set `undeployOldVersions` and `autoDeploy` to true so that tomcat automatically deploys the app and removes the old version if it is no longer necessary.
Check https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html for further info on tomcat's config.

The Version after the ## must be string comparable, so you can use e.g. a build number from your CI System but you may have to zero pad it.

There are a few things to look out for:

- External resources need to be shareable, if you are using a database but your new versions needs a new schema you'll run into problems. Or if you open a TCP listener on a specific port it is also not shareable.
- Caches, if your application uses internal caches they should be write through and expire quickly
- The app must be undeployable

Comment: opengrok does open a listening TCP socket, for configuration updates.  so, your answer is non-conclusive in regards to how it applies to opengrok.